# XFCE super shortcut disable super+* shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I assigned <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to tile window on left or right.

It works.

I assigned <kbd>Super</kbd> to open whisker menu (`xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`)

It works but <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> keyboard shortcut no works any more

Is there a way to make these shortcut work together?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/)

Comment: @IporSircer https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/libxfce4ui/-/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, as @ipor-sircer suggested a bug report is necessary on this case to get this fixed on future releases. ([current bug report](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/libxfce4ui/-/issues/1) as you commented)

Awaiting an official fix you can reassign `Super` to an other key like `F14` then use `F14`/`F14 + ←` for your shortcuts, this can be done with [xmodmap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices) for instance